# what does s{SOMESTR}{$myvar} mean in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

Someone has written something like the following code  :

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
my $myVar = 'somecomplicatedString'; 
my $someString = 'mySystemvariable=SOMESTR';
if ( $someString =~ /SOMESTR/ ) {
        $someSting =~ s{SOMESTR}{$myVar}
}
# $someString now equals 'mySystemvariable=somecomplicatedString'
```

What is the difference between the `s///` operator and the `s{}{}` operator?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use any set of delimiter in Perl match operator - `m//`, or substitution operator - `s///`.

Other examples:

```
s#oldTest#newTest#
s/oldTest/newTest/
s!oldTest!newTest!
s~oldTest~newTest~
s{oldTest}{newTest}   # Here we use appropriate opening and closing braces.

m/someText/
m!someText!
/someText/   # You can omit the `m` when `/` is delimiter
!someText!   # This is Wrong. You can't omit `m` in other delimiter.
```

The major advantage you see with varying delimiter is that you can avoid escaping a delimiter in the text, by using a different character as delimiter.
So, using `#` as delimiter, you don't need to escape `/` in the string.

From [perlop doc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators):

Under `m//` operator section:

> If `"/"` is the delimiter then the initial `m` is optional. With the `m` you can use any pair of non-whitespace (ASCII) characters as delimiters. This is particularly useful for matching path names that contain `"/"`, to avoid LTS (leaning toothpick syndrome). If `"?"` 
>   is the delimiter, then a match-only-once rule applies, described in `m?PATTERN?` below.

Under `s///` operator section:

> Any non-whitespace delimiter may replace the slashes. Add space after the s when using a character allowed in identifiers.

Comment: and the upside of that is that it reduces the need for quoting, for example when you have slashes inside of the expression. You can just use a different set of delimiters.

Answer (score 5):

It is the same operator, but using different delimiters which can be used to achieve better readability.
`{}` are convenient when using `/e` modifier,

```
$string =~ s{(\d)}{
  # ...
  $1 + 1;
}e;
```

Comment: I never think about this kind of `s`. Thank you for example