# s[][] notation in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have seen this `perl` code on the `cpan` documentation for a module:

```
$filename =~ s[^.+/][];
```

What does this mean?  I am used to the `s//` notation for the `s` function.

Comment: Related: [what does s{SOMESTR}{$myvar} mean in perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18354691/176646), [Curly brackets in regexps with Perl](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22454089/176646)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perl allows any non-whitespace character to be used as a string delimiter. See [*Quote and Quote-like Operators*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators)

Bracketing characters are used in pairs, like `<...>`, `[...]`, `(...)`, and `{...}`, while single-quotes prevent interpolation. Otherwise the functionality is identical to that of the default delimiter

In this case

```
$filename =~ s[^.+/][]
```

is the same as

```
$filename =~ s/^.+\///
```

but is far more readable

I tend to prefer the pipe character `|` which looks similar to the usual slash

```
$filename =~ s|^.+/||
```

but the choice is up to you

Comment: But in the code I gave there is both the `[` and `]` characters, so it is not just a replacement of the `/` character.  There is something else going on.

Comment: @CJ7 See the [docs for `s///`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#s%2f_PATTERN_%2f_REPLACEMENT_%2fmsixpodualngcer): "Any non-whitespace delimiter may replace the slashes...If the PATTERN is delimited by bracketing quotes, the REPLACEMENT has its own pair of quotes, which may or may not be bracketing quotes, for example, `s(foo)(bar)` or `s<foo>/bar/`."

Comment: @CJ7 You can also prove this to yourself using [B::Deparse](https://metacpan.org/pod/B::Deparse): `perl -MO=Deparse -e's[foo][bar]'` prints `s/foo/bar/;`

Comment: @CJ7: As I tried to explain, if the delimiter chosen is one of the four opening bracket characters then its pair is used as the closing character. The substitution `s///` has *two* parameters, so both must be delimited and it appears as `s(...)(...)` or even `s<...>{...}` or `s/.../[...]`

Comment: `%` cannot be used

Comment: @CJ7: Not true. `perl -E 'my $s = "abc"; $s =~ s%b%x%; say $s;'` prints `axc`. Not that I would  recommend it as it's not very readable

Answer (score 0):

It's just an alternative pattern delimiter.  Depending on the details of the pattern - in particular, if the pattern has slashes in it - it may be easier for humans to parse the expression if something other than the slash is used as a delimiter.  In this case its a little marginal but, if you used the slash it would look like this:

```
$filename =~ s/^.+\///;
```

You can immediately see how its harder to figure out which slashes are part of the pattern and which delimit the pattern.  In this case the third last slash is part of the pattern and would be interpreted as ending the pattern and hence has to be escaped.

Comment: But in the code I gave there is both the `[` and `]` characters, so it is not just a replacement of the `/` character. There is something else going on.

Comment: The natural "partner" of  [  is  ]  , so strictly speaking, I guess you are right - but apart from replacing one '/' with [ and the other with ], - it __*is*__ the same in effect.  You can see how much easier it is to interpret the pattern that way - finally, the other answerer has over 84k points and is saying the same thing - not likely (s)he is wrong, yes? ;-)